# How do I force gpspipe to read from a USB Serial device rather than a server address with a port and everything

Tags: gps, serial

I'm desperately trying to grab the simplest piece of information I can out of my usb dongle from the command line. A program of mine needs to use it so it has to be a STDIN/STDOUT type solution.

I have a GlobalSat ND-100 which has a fix on my position (that Google Earth can and is currently using) which is very accurate. So I know the device is working. I have a mac.

I've tried these techniques so far to try to grab my current location:

-read directly from the usbserial (fails. binary? data)

```
  cat /dev/cu.usbserial
  #for some weird reason this doesn't return anything right now...it did before. anyway, it doesn't work.
```

-use gpspipe (installed along with gpsd) to grab the sentences

```
sudo gpspipe -rs /dev/cu.usbserial
#=> gpspipe: could not connect to gpsd localhost:2947, Unknown error: -6(-6)
```

So gpspipe is looking for a server, not a serial port. I need it to use the serial port. Or maybe I could host the usb serial port on a server. How might I do that?

Comment: you might be better of using gpsbabel for mac http://www.gpsbabel.org/download.html

Comment: cool, this program has a terminal version you can download on mac with `brew install gpsbabel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check this is to see if your are getting any data from the usb gps dongle on screen
Try this in Python

```
#       testgps.py\
import gps, os, time
session = gps.gps(host="localhost", port="2947")
session.poll()
session.stream()
while 1:
   os.system("clear")
   session.poll()
# a = altitude, d = date/time, m=mode,
# o=postion/fix, s=status, y=satellites
   print
   print "GPS reading"
   print "---------------------"
   print "latitude " , session.fix.latitude
   print "longitude " , session.fix.longitude
   print "time GPS " ,  session.fix.time
   print 'time ticks' , time.time()

    print 'time GMT ' , time.gmtime()

   print "Satellites (total of", len(session.satellites) , " in view)"
   time.sleep(1)
   for i in session.satellites:
      print "t", i
   time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: This creates a server on localhost:2947, correct?

Comment: I am getting an error with gpspipe please look and advise _ E unlink(""/dev/ttyS10""): Permission denied"   
gpspipe: error opening serial port_